# Empty RouteService with Apache Camel 2.20.0

Tags: apache, routes

we are currently trying to upgrade from Camel 2.19.0 to 2.20.0.

We have one timed routed which schedule autostart = false

```
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component
public class AdaptionService extends SpringRouteBuilder {

@Value("${control.timer.cron}")
private String timerCron;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("quartz2://adaptionServices/UserUpdateTimer?cron=" + timerCron)
        .routeId("scheduler").autoStartup(false)
        .to("direct:route-userUpdate");

    from("direct:route-userUpdate")
        .routeId("adaption_service")
        .log("Executing Adaption Service (timed)");

}
```

No in the CamelContextConfiguration I try to star the timer route (I know I could simply achieve this by autoStartup(true). It is just an example to abstract from more complex use case we have.

```
@Configuration
public class CamelApplicationContextConfiguration implements CamelContextConfiguration {

@Override
public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
    camelContext.setUseMDCLogging(true);
}

@Override
public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
    try {
        camelContext.startRoute("scheduler");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

That does not work. I checked startRoute(..) and appearently the routeService inside the camelContext is completely empty. With 2.19.0 this works without a flaw.

Any suggestions?

Regards
Holger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camel 2.20 release has changed the startup logic when using Spring / Spring-Boot with Camel. You can see that in the release notes.

However we should make `CamelContextConfiguration` call the `afterApplicationStart` at a later stage. And also document this API a bit better when its called:

I have logged a ticket about this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11945

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thank you Claus:)